# AngularJS - using setters and getters within a Service to store variables. Is it possible?

Tags: angularjs

If I ran the code below would a variable called language that exists within a service be able to be set and taken from various controllers?

```
app.service('serviceName', function() {

       var language;

       this.getLanguage = function()
       {
        return language;
       }

       this.setLanguage = function(lan)
       {
      language = lan;
       }
    });
```

Controller 1:

```
serviceName.setLanguage('english');
```

Controller 2:

```
$scope.lan = serviceName.getLanguage();
```

Also if this is undesirable what would be a better way to keep variables in a service that can be accessed throughout different controllers?

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Answer (score 1):

You can also combine everything in a single method:

```
app.service('serviceName', function () {
    var _language;

    this.language = function(value){
        if(value){
            _language = value;
        } else {
            return _language;
        }
    };
});
```

Your case is pretty simple, so you can even just expose the variable directly:

```
app.service('serviceName', function () {
    this.language = null;
});
```